# Angular multiple routes in child module

Tags: angular, routes

If I have a Angular module, with these routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'route1', children: [
    {path: '', component: route1Component}
  ]},
  {path: 'route2', children: [
    {path: '', component: route2Component}
  ]},
  {path: 'route3', children: [
    {path: '', component: route3Component}
  ]}
];
```

how can I then use the routes in a parent module, where I would lazy load.
Normally I would do something like this

```
{path: 'route1', loadChildren: () => import('../child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule)}
```

but that normaly implies that the child route has a default route, and here I have 3

I would like to just import the module, and get all the routes from that module

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide any one route as default to the router in lazy loaded.
So I would suggest to just define the default router and redirect it to the first route.

So you can have the following code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {path:''',redirectTo:'route1',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: 'route1', children: [
    {path: '', component: route1Component}
  ]},
  {path: 'route2', children: [
    {path: '', component: route2Component}
  ]},
  {path: 'route3', children: [
    {path: '', component: route3Component}
  ]}
];
```

This would resolve your issue of not defining any default router.

Comment: thanks, but it does not quite solve my problem. How do I then route to "route2" and "route3" from the parent ?

Comment: Then you have to put some link in route1 to redirect to the route2 and route3. 
If you not want to put that, than there is no way to use them as one module and keeping direct link,
Then it would be better to make three child module. You are conflicting the basic concept.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this is the first time I get this problem. I will simply just add the components to the parent module, even though it is not ideal